# Kubernetes configuring master and slave in AWS EC2 instance- getting error while config in slave after giving token

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying to register the master node in slave node. I'm using AWS EC2 instance's i configured docker and Kubernetes in both the instances.

I've followed below steps:

After both instance launched

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo su -

apt-get install docker.io
ls /etc/docker
    
    
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "exec-opts": ["native.cgroupdriver=systemd"],
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
    "max-size": "100m"
  },
  "storage-driver": "overlay2"
}
EOF

systemctl enable docker
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker

apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl && curl -fsSLo /usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg

    
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/kubernetes-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list


apt-get update && apt-get install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl && apt-mark hold kubelet kubeadm kubectl
```

=======Master==========

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=172.31.25.122 --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --ignore-preflight-errors=NumCPU
```

output:
kubeadm join 172.31.25.122:6443 --token ioewww.jrqwngf1t6ji94yp 
--discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:de6116a51a8cae8b128f311d08ba47b2c381bd97403aae8da2a062cf89c83cb3

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
  sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
  sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

    
    
cat $HOME/.kube/config

kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.21/manifests/calico.yaml
```

======Slave=============

Run Token which you got from the master

```
sudo su -

kubeadm join 172.31.25.122:6443 --token ioewww.jrqwngf1t6ji94yp \
        --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:de6116a51a8cae8b128f311d08ba47b2c381bd97403aae8da2a062cf89c83cb3
```

i got below Error

root@slave:~# kubectl get pods
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
root@slave:~# kubeadm join 172.31.25.122:6443 --token ioewww.jrqwngf1t6ji94yp 
--discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:de6116a51a8cae8b128f311d08ba47b2c381bd97403aae8da2a062cf89c83cb3
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[WARNING SystemVerification]: missing optional cgroups: blkio
error execution phase preflight: couldn't validate the identity of the API Server: Get "https://172.31.25.122:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info?timeout=10s": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher

I'm getting error in slave after giving the token which is generated in master node. could someone please help me on this. how I can overcome this error